# File I/O In DrScheme

Tags: file, file-io, io, racket

(read) takes in a string from stdin, parses it as an s-expression, and returns that expression. How do I do the exact same thing, except taking input from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these:

```
(call-with-input-file "foo" read)
(with-input-from-file "foo" read)
```

The first will open the file and apply `read` on the open port to read a value and finally close it.  The second is similar, except that it applies the function on no arguments in a dynamic context where the current input is read from the file.  There are a bunch of other ways to do this, but you'll need to ask a more specific question...

(BTW, in the current repository version, which will be released as 4.2.3 soon, there is a new `file->list` function that will `read` all sexpressions from the file and return a list holding all of them.)