# Creating Lists from files in Scheme

Tags: list, file, file-io, scheme

I've worked out how to read in the file and it works using the following code:

```
(define p (read(open-input-file "starbucks4.sxml")))
```

But how do i store `p` as a list with elements separated by `\n` characters.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a solution in pure scheme or can you use implementation-specific library functions? If the latter, you should add which implementation you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) (or PLT Scheme), you can use the [`read-line`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7e23%7e25kernel%29._read-line%29%29) function to read each line of the file to get them -- but they won't be read as s-exps, each will simply be a string.

Comment: Note also that in Racket you have a convenient [`file->lines`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/file..rkt%29._file-%7e3elines%29%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, both MIT Scheme and Racket, as far as some other implementations, have functions `call-with-input-file` and `call-with-output-file`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713332/file-i-o-in-drscheme) for details of their usage and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/File-Ports.html) for complete reference.

As for a `\n` separated list, the best approach I know is using Common Lisp style [`format`](http://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/schemexref.cgi?format) function. But if your implementation does't have such function, you will need to manually break your list and print it using `write` function.

Comment: Yes, you should use `call-with-input-file` or `with-input-from-file` to close the file when you're done reading it.  As for your suggested use of `format` -- that is irrelevant here, `format` is used to assemble strings, not to deconstruct one.`

Comment: As far as I understand, the question was about outputting elements of list, separated by `\n`. If this is true, you will need to format string anyway, and I don't know a better way to do it then CL `format` function. If it is available, of course.